# Full width button, how to align text

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Trying to figure out if I can align the text in a full width button, i.e a button that has `width: double.infinity`

for example this:

```
ButtonTheme(
  minWidth: double.infinity,
  child: FlatButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('Sign Out', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
  ),
)
```

produces a centered text button and the alignment cannot be changed.

I have tried a few things but can't figure it out, unless I try to create a custom button.

I'm trying to get a full width button with text:left so the user can click anywhere in the row, and still get the material tap effect.

[image]

Answer (score 28):

I found out that `RawMaterialButton`'s build-Method the child is [always centered](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button.dart#L195):

```
child: Center(
  widthFactor: 1.0,
  heightFactor: 1.0,
  child: widget.child,
),
```

To have the text to be aligned to start/left you could give it an infinite width, which would make it as wide as its parent, the Center widget.

```
child: FlatButton(
  child: SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Text(
      'Sign out',
      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
);
```

Comment: I was using this inside a ListView, and it threw an exception because the height was not set. How can I set the height?
Since, this solution did not work, I put the Button inside a row, and set `mainAxisAlignment` to `start`, 

Refer to my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58551964/2594980

Answer (score 10):

A simple workaround would be setting Align button text to `Alignment.centerLeft` as -

```
  MaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
    textColor: Colors.white,
    color: Colors.grey,
    child: Align(
       alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
           'SUBMIT',
            style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
              ),
        ),
 ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer since the current one is more of a "hack". You don't generally want a lot of infinite large children lying around.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple hack would be to put the button inside a Row with only one element, and set the `mainAxisAlignment` to `start`.

```
Row(
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
 children: <Widget>[
  FlatButton(
   onPressed: () {},
   child: Text('Sign Out')
  ),  // end of FlatButton
 ], // end of widgets
), // end of Row
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code**

```
Container(
   color: Colors.grey,
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0),
   child: ButtonTheme(
    child: FlatButton(
      onPressed: _showDatePicker,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Text('Sign Out',
          textAlign: TextAlign.right, // center, right
              ),
           ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use an `Expanded` widget

```
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.description),
            ),
            Text("Detalles"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```