# Aligning text in AppBar button

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to align a text in a button positioned in action property of AppBar..

[image]

I want the text to be on the right..

```
     AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text(
                'Done',
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      )
```

I have even tried `MaterialRawButton` with same result... The text will be in the centre of the button no matter what you do

Comment: Making a custom button might be the only way in this case. [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156163/full-width-button-how-to-align-text) , it is mentioned here that the `RawMaterialButton`'s [build-Method](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button.dart#L195) the child is always centered. 

For custom button you can try [Inkwell example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267502/how-to-align-text-in-a-button-in-flutter/56269627) or as you mentioned using `Stack` .

Comment: @dev-aentgs Yes I'm afraid that you're right. Matter of fact I already making my own button. I just hope someone else will come with some solution to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use IconButton instead and add into icon parameter text widget.

```
             IconButton(
              icon: Text(
                'Done',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using widthFactor in Align ,which allow us to move at specific place.
**Just add this code in Align**

```
widthFactor: 2.5
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer however 1/ setting width doesn't move the text to the right. It only change size of the button..2/ Setting padding will works but the padding would have to be adjusted for different texts length so that isn't very nice solution. I can also use `Stack` and create my custom button but I hope there is proper solution to this simple task

Comment: Just figured out , you can used width factor in align. It help us to move text at specific place. Try this **widthFactor: 2.5,** in Align

Comment: hmm... You might be on to something.. That however messing with width of the button but it makes the text to be aligned where it should be... Please amend your question with the code and if anyone else will not have better solution then I will mark your answer as answered

Comment: Sure, At first I thought the same, but it doesn't messed with width , I tried keeping a two appbar , one with original and other with container. Both turn out same size.check this <https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b>

Comment: ok... I don't think anyone will come up with better idea so I'm marking this as answered